Which diagram for crystal field splitting of Square Planar is accurate?
I have come across these two splitting. Which of these is correct when there is crystal field splitting of ligand in square planar manner.


Kindly provide reference of books and plausible explanation as well.

The difference between the diagrams reflects the fact that the orbital energy levels change when you put electrons into them and the electrons electrostatically repel one another. The first diagram is for one electron, the second shows what happens as a result of having eight electrons crowd into those $d$ orbitals.
In the first diagram we assume that just one electron is in the $d$ orbitals so there is not any repulsion between them. We just have the repulsion experienced by this electron from the ligands (in crystal field theory). This repulsion is inevitably least with the $m=0$ ($d_{z^2}$, with the ligands in the $xy$ plane) orbital and greatest with the $m=\pm2$ ($d_{xy},d_{x^2-y^2}$) orbitals. The latter two orbitals,in turn, are split because one orbital is directed right at the repelling ligand electrons and the other is tucked in between.
The second diagram takes account of the electron-electron repulsions when, as usual for square planar complexes, there are eight $d$ electrons and they are repelling one another as well as repelling the ligand electrons. We start here with the $m=\pm2$ orbitals in the plane of the ligands. Again one of these is directed right at the ligands and is at highest energy, the other is directed between the ligands and is at somewhat lower energy. Only the orbital directed between the ligands, ($d_{x^2-y^2}$), is occupied.
This has a major effect on the $m=\pm1$ orbitals, labeled $d_{xz}$ and $d_{yz}$. Repelled more strongly by the occupied $d_{x^2-y^2}$ orbital in the ligand plane than by the more distant ligand electrons, these orbitals lower their energy by rotating to line up with the ligands instead of the occupied orbital. The $m=0$ ($d_{z^2}$) orbital lacks this degree of freedom due to its rotational symmetry, and can only watch the $m=\pm1$ orbitals drop below it in energy as they optimize their orientation.
